# enable JDBC connection to DB2 server database

Tags: database, jdbc, db2

I have a DB2 server setup ready (DB2 installed on a remote server that can be accessed via SSH).

Somewhere else I have an application. I would like that application to be able to connect to that DB2 database via jdbc.
The url looks like: `jdbc:db2://xxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50000/mydb` to which I add a user and password.

The command: `db2 get db cfg for mydb | grep -i restrict` returns `Restrict access = NO`

The details of the DB are

```
Database alias                       = MYDB
 Database name                        = MYDB
 Local database directory             = /disk1
 Database release level               = 10.00
 Comment                              =
 Directory entry type                 = Indirect
 Catalog database partition number    = 0
 Alternate server hostname            =
 Alternate server port number         =
```

How can I connect to the database? I tried with `root` and other user but it fails.

The application returns:

`Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.DisconnectNonTransientConnectionException: [jcc][t4][2030][11211][3.69.24] A communication error occurred during operations on the connection's underlying socket, socket input stream, 
or socket output stream.  Error location: Reply.fill() - socketInputStream.read (-1).  Message: Connection reset. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001`

Comment: Please provide more detail as to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: edited question to include more details

Comment: Maybe try adding details like JDBC URL you're using, the code that tries to make the connection, what error you get from the application, etc.

Comment: @Ian I added some extra information

Comment: Are the details of the DB that you provided from the DB2 server or from the client?  They indicate that `MYDB` is a remote database, so if you're seeing this on the *server* you may want to investigate.

Comment: @Ian sorry I copied the wrong one ... I changed in question